# Insert multiples images in a column of an article

Tags: article, sidewaysfigure

I'm trying to put 3 figures on a column of an article.

I would like to put this figures in 3 subplots.

The first would be alone followed by 2 smaller subfigures in the other line like this:

[image]

But it has to fit in one column of the article document:

**Edited:**
Here is the code":

```
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.97\linewidth}
    \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagens/improviso.jpg}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{0.97\linewidth}
        \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{imagens/compositor.jpg}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    \begin{subfigure}{0.97\linewidth}
        \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{imagens/Hibrido.jpg}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}    
  \caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure}
```

Thank's very much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us, how you try to insert your pictures in your document. The best is in form small but complete document, which we can compile!. Usualy help, if yiu define image width something like this: `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{<image>}`

Comment: Code added. Thanks very much =)

Comment: But it is not complete! I asked you for complete document, which we can compile as it is!. Please extend your code fragment to it (add document preamble with relevant packages). We haven't any idea about your document layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more example ... Using `subfigure` from the `subcaption` package and answer of koleygr as OP MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `minipage`s and `subcaption` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
    \begin{minipage}[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]{\linewidth}
    \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \captionof{subfigure}{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{minipage}\\
    \hfill\begin{minipage}{0.46\linewidth}
        \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
      \captionof{subfigure}{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.46\linewidth}
        \centering
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
      \captionof{subfigure}{Lorem ipsum}
    \end{minipage}\hfill\null    
  \caption{Caption place holder}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend you to using [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package. The package provides a means of using facilities analagous to those of the caption package, when writing captions for subfigures and the like. See code below and attached figure.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{mwe}

    \begin{document}
    \blindtext
        \begin{figure}[ht!]
            \centering     
            \subcaptionbox{ Text1 \label{figA}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}} 
            \subcaptionbox{ Text2 \label{figB}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
            \subcaptionbox{ Text3 \label{figC}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
            \caption{Text}
            \label{AES:fig_MUE6_311}
        \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

If you would like to put third image on the next line, just only add `\newline` or better `\linebreak`:

```
    \subcaptionbox{ Text1 \label{figA}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}} \newline
    \subcaptionbox{ Text2 \label{figB}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}} 
    \subcaptionbox{ Text3 \label{figC}}{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
```

[image]